# How to block ads on Chrome for Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I am using Adaway & ads are blocked across different apps on my phone. However, Ads on Chrome Mobile are not getting blocked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

AdAway (root) SHOULD block all ad-hosts. So in my case, chrome blocks all ads on webpages because it can not load them cause of blocking the ad-host system wide.

Try updating the host lists in AdAway.

Comment: not working for me. I updated Adaway, still no luck

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately chrome still doesn't support extensions.  You should look at Firefox if you want to block ads. Firefox for android support extensions just like desktop version.

Comment: Adblock plus is available for Firefox...

Comment: Adaway is not a chrome extension!

Comment: I didn't say it is a chrome extension. Adaway like apps won't work for the browsers. So I suggested Firefox for you.

Comment: Adaway works for browsers, because it blocks the hosts system wide.

Comment: Then why do you think it is not working for chrome?

Comment: It could not work because the ad's host isn't registered in the AdAway host lists or AdAway wasn't applied properly.

Comment: Try AdFree Android from Big Tin Can and see if that works, I have never had adverts in any browser using it. The only time they get through is if it is a new host and AdFree hasn't yet updated to block it.

Answer (score -3):

just turn off reduce data in settings and you should see no ads!